# Вставьте, где это необходимо, пропущенные знаки препинания:

Tags: пунктуация

При совокупности преступления суд определяет наказание путём поглощения менее строгого наказания более строгим либо путём полного или частичного сложения наказаний. В срок предварительного следствия включается время со дня возбуждения дела и до момента направления прокурору дела с обвинительным заключением или постановлением о передаче дела в суд для рассмотрения вопроса о применении принудительных мер медицинского характера или до прекращения или приостановления производства по делу.

Comment: Мы не выполняем задания (в особенности домашние), но можем проверить **уже выполненные** *вами*. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос, добавив свой вариант ответа. Подробнее о том, как задавать вопросы, читайте в Справке.

Answer (score -1):

При совокупности преступления суд определяет наказание путём поглощения менее строгого наказания более *строгим,* либо путём полного или частичного сложения наказаний. В срок предварительного следствия включается время со дня возбуждения *дела,* и до момента направления прокурору дела с обвинительным заключением или постановлением о передаче дела в суд для рассмотрения вопроса о применении принудительных мер медицинского *характера,* или до прекращения или приостановления производства по делу.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, на чём основана постановка всех запятых?

Comment: Пожалуйста, не делайте домашки за тех, кто их даже не пытался сделать.